# optimize a large angularjs table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the case, I am trying to optimize a table that is used to calculate financial report(a little bit similar to excel). The terrible thing is the whole table structure is stored on server including even rowspan and td colspan. So it produces like 3000 cells, and once one binds with watchers. We test it with IE 10 on a 4GB Memory, i3 processor laptop, you know what happened then. I tried to replace some binding with one-time binding as much as I could, I wrote a directive to dynamically create minimal cell content and I tried to avoid using isolated-scope directives. All those methods don't help much. Can give some suggestion that what else I can do with it? Many Thanks!

```
<table id="main_table_{{uitab.id}}"
                            class="table_new_style table table-new-border"
                            style="table-layout: fixed; margin-bottom: 0;"
                            ng-style="{'width':uitab.table.width?uitab.table.width+'px':'100%'}">
                            <thead>
                                <tr ng-repeat="uiheadrow in uitab.table.thead.headRows" style = "height:0px;">
                                    <th ng-repeat="uiheadcell in uiheadrow.headCells"
                                        ng-hide="uiheadcell.hide"
                                        ng-attr-rowspan="{{uiheadcell.rowspan}}"
                                        ng-attr-colspan="{{uiheadcell.colspan}}"
                                        style="padding:0;border:0;height:0px;"
                                        ng-style="{'width':uiheadcell.width+'%'}">
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="uirow in uitab.table.tbody.rows |filter:uitab.table.filterChoose"
                                    ng-init="rowIndex = $index+1;"
                                    ng-hide="uirow.del||uirow.hide" ng-post-repeat-directive
                                    >
                                    <!-- style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;"  
                                    'nowrap':uicell.nowrap,
                                    -->
                                    <td
                                        ng-class="{'invalide':uicell.invalide}"
                                        ng-repeat="uicell in uirow.cells"
                                        ng-hide="uicell.hide"
                                        ng-style="{'text-align':uicell.align}"
                                        ng-attr-colspan="{{uicell.colspan}}" 
                                        ng-attr-rowspan="{{uicell.rowspan}}"
                                        ng-dblclick="editTextArea(uicell)"                                                                                                                      
                                    >
                                        <input type="checkbox" ng-if="uicell.dataType=='checkbox'"
                                        ng-model="uirow.checked"> <!-- <div class="checkbox" ng-if="uicell.dataType=='checkbox'">
                                        <label> 
                                            <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="uicell.checked">{{uicell.label}}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>  --> <!-- ng-disabled="uirow.id" --> <select
                                        style="width: 100%;position: relative;z-index: 1;"
                                        onchange="window.changeflag=true"
                                        ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}"
                                        ng-focus="inputFocus(uicell)"
                                        ng-blur="uicell.validate();exeFuncs(uitab)"
                                        ng-if="(uicell.dataType=='select'&&!uicell.custom&&!uirow.id)"
                                        ng-model="uicell.value"
                                        ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in uicell.options">
                                    </select> <input
                                        id="{{'select_'+uitab.id+'_'+uirow.rowIndex+'_'+uicell.colIndex}}"
                                        ng-if="(uicell.dataType=='select'&&uicell.custom&&!uirow.id)||uicell.writeable"
                                        ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}"
                                        onchange="window.changeflag=true"
                                        ng-focus="inputFocus(uicell)"
                                        ng-blur="uicell.validate();exeFuncs(uitab)" placeholder="请选择"
                                        style="width: 100%;" type="text" ng-select
                                        ng-select-topoffset="{{uimodule.tabs.length==1?30:0}}"
                                        ng-select-cell="uicell" ng-model="uicell.selectname" /> <span
                                        ng-if="(uicell.dataType=='select'&&uirow.id)&&!uicell.writeable"
                                        ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}"
                                        ng-repeat="option in uicell.options|filter:uicell.value">{{option.name}}</span>
                                        <span ng-if="uicell.dataType=='label'"
                                        ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}">{{uicell.value}}{{uicell.serial?rowIndex:''}}</span>
                                        <a
                                        ng-href="/download.sword?ctrl=DemoCtrl_downloadallfile&mbpath={{uicell.value}}{{getAuditParams()}}"
                                        ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}"
                                        ng-if="uicell.dataType=='href'&&uicell.value"
                                        style="font-weight: bold;" target="_blank">{{uirow.data[uicell.labelProperty]}}</a>
                                        <span ng-if="uicell.dataType=='href'&&!uicell.value"
                                        ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}">{{uirow.data[uicell.labelProperty]}}</span>

                                        <a
                                        href="javascript:;"
                                        ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}"
                                        ng-click="showDialog(uicell, uirow)"
                                        ng-if="((uicell.dataType=='dialog'&&(uirow.data[uicell.dataSource])) || ((uicell.dataType=='TAB') && uicell.href != '' && uicell.href != '/'))"
                                        style="font-weight: bold;">{{uirow.data[uicell.labelProperty]}}</a>
                                        <span ng-if="((uicell.dataType=='dialog'&&!(uirow.data[uicell.dataSource])) || ((uicell.dataType=='TAB') && (uicell.href == '' || uicell.href == '/')))"
                                        ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}">{{uirow.data[uicell.labelProperty]}}</span>

                                        <input ng-if="uicell.dataType=='text'"
                                        ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}"
                                        ng-focus="inputFocus(uicell)"
                                        ng-blur="uicell.validate();exeFuncs(uitab)"
                                        onchange="window.changeflag=true"
                                        ng-paste-text ng-paste-cell='uicell' ng-paste-row='uirow' ng-paste-table="uitab.table.tbody" ng-paste-tab="uitab"
                                        style="width: 100%;" type="text" ng-model="uicell.value" /> <!-- ng-click="editTextArea(uicell.value)" -->
                                        <div ng-if="uicell.dataType=='disable'">
                                            <span ng-if="uicell.value">{{uicell.value}}</span> <span
                                                ng-if="!uicell.value">---</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- ng-autotextarea -->
                                        <div ng-if="uicell.dataType=='textarea'" ng-attr-id="{{uitab.id+'_'+uirow.rowIndex+'_'+uicell.colIndex}}"
                                            ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}"                                           
                                            style="outline:none;position: relative;z-index: 1;margin: 3px;min-height:16px;white-space:normal;word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word; "
                                            ng-bind-html="getTextareaDivText(uicell.value)"
                                            ng-paste-text ng-paste-cell='uicell' ng-paste-row='uirow' ng-paste-table="uitab.table.tbody" ng-paste-tab="uitab" 
                                            contenteditable="true" ng-model="uicell.value"
                                        >
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- <div
                                             ng-if="uicell.dataType=='textarea'"
                                             style="margin: 3px;"
                                        > 
                                            <textarea
                                                ng-focus="inputFocus(uicell)"
                                                ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}"
                                                ng-blur="uicell.validate()"
                                                ng-click="editTextArea(uicell)"
                                                onchange="window.changeflag=true"
                                                readonly="readonly"
                                                ng-style="{'height':getTextAreaHeight(uirow)+'px'}"
                                                style="width:100%;resize: none;overflow: hidden;"
                                                ng-model="uicell.value"></textarea>
                                        </div> -->
                                        <!-- <div ng-if="uicell.dataType=='textarea2'">
                                            <div style="margin-top: 6px; float: right; width: 30px;"
                                                ng-if="uicell.showEditBtn">
                                                <a ng-click="editTextArea(uicell)"
                                                    ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}"
                                                    href="javascript:;"><i class="primary icon-zoom-in"></i></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div
                                                style="width: auto;">
                                                <textarea ng-focus="inputFocus(uicell)"
                                                    ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}"
                                                    ng-blur="uicell.validate()"
                                                    ng-dblclick="editTextArea(uicell)"
                                                    onchange="window.changeflag=true"
                                                    ng-style="{'overflow-y':uicell.height>16?'auto':'hidden','height':uicell.height+'px'}"
                                                    style="width:100%;resize: none;overflow: hidden;"
                                                    ng-style="{'height':getTextAreaHeight(uicell)+'px'}"
                                                    ng-change="resetTextAreaHeight(uicell)"
                                                    ng-model="uicell.value"></textarea> 
                                                    ng-keyup="resetTextAreaHeightOnKeyup($event,uicell)"

                                                    ng-style="{'height':uicell.height+'px'}"

                                                    <textarea ng-focus="inputFocus(uicell)"
                                                    ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}"
                                                    ng-blur="uicell.validate()"
                                                    ng-dblclick="editTextArea(uicell)"
                                                    onchange="window.changeflag=true"
                                                    ng-autotextarea
                                                    readonly="readonly"
                                                    onpaste="myFunction(event)"

                                                    style="width:100%;resize: none;overflow: hidden;height:16px;"
                                                    ng-model="uicell.value"></textarea>
                                                    <div 
                                                        ng-blur="uicell.validate()"
                                                        ng-dblclick="editTextArea(uicell)" 
                                                        class="test_box" 
                                                        readonly="readonly"
                                                        oninput="window.changeflag=true;"
                                                        ng-model="uicell.value"
                                                        >{{uicell.value}}</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> -->
                                        <div ng-if="uicell.dataType=='upload'&&uirow.id&&uicell.haveCjmbFlag&&uitab.id!='10101-1'&&uitab.id!='10101-2'
                                                    &&uitab.id!='10101-3'&&uitab.id!='10201-1'&&uitab.id!='10201-2'&&uitab.id!='10201-3'&&uitab.id!='10201-3'&&uitab.id!='10301-1'">
                                            <a ng-show="uicell.ftjlURL"
                                                href="javascript:;"
                                                ng-click="openFtjl(uicell.ftjlURL)">访谈</a>
                                            <a href="javascript:;"
                                                ng-fileupload-url="{{uicell.uploadUrl}}"
                                                ng-fileupload-param='{"xmid":"{{xmid}}","cjbddm":"{{cjbddm}}","cjbgdm":"{{uitab.id}}","cjmxdm":"{{uirow.data.cjmxdm}}"}'
                                                ng-fileupload-cell='uicell' ng-fileupload-row='uirow'
                                                ng-fileupload-template='{{uirow.data[uicell.templateProperty]}}'
                                                ng-fileupload>上传</a> <a ng-show="uicell.value"
                                                href="javascript:;"
                                                ng-click="viewFile(uirow.data.cjmxdm,uicell.isRefXm)">预览({{uirow.data.fjsl}})</a>
                                            <a ng-show="uicell.value" href="javascript:;"
                                                ng-click="delFile(uirow.data.cjmxdm,uicell,uirow)">删除</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div ng-if="uicell.dataType=='upload'&&uirow.id&&!uicell.haveCjmbFlag">
                                            <a href="javascript:;"
                                                ng-fileupload-url="{{uicell.uploadUrl}}"
                                                ng-fileupload-param='{"xmid":"{{xmid}}","cjbddm":"{{cjbddm}}","cjbgdm":"{{uitab.id}}","cjmxdm":"{{uirow.data.cjmxdm}}"}'
                                                ng-fileupload-cell='uicell' ng-fileupload-row='uirow'
                                                ng-fileupload-template='{{uirow.data[uicell.templateProperty]}}'
                                                ng-fileupload>上传</a> <a ng-show="uicell.value"
                                                href="javascript:;" ng-click="viewFile(uirow.data.cjmxdm,uicell.isRefXm)">预览({{uirow.data.fjsl}})</a>
                                            <a ng-show="uicell.value" href="javascript:;"
                                                ng-click="delFile(uirow.data.cjmxdm,uicell,uirow)">删除</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div ng-if="uicell.dataType=='upload'&&uirow.id&&uicell.haveCjmbFlag&&(uitab.id=='10101-1'||uitab.id=='10101-2'
                                                    ||uitab.id=='10101-3'||uitab.id=='10201-1'||uitab.id=='10201-2'||uitab.id=='10201-3'||uitab.id=='10201-3'||uitab.id=='10301-1')">
                                            <a href="javascript:;"
                                                ng-fileupload-url="{{uicell.uploadUrl}}"
                                                ng-fileupload-param='{"xmid":"{{xmid}}","cjbddm":"{{cjbddm}}","cjbgdm":"{{uitab.id}}","cjmxdm":"{{uirow.data.cjmxdm}}"}'
                                                ng-fileupload-cell='uicell' ng-fileupload-row='uirow'
                                                ng-fileupload-template='{{uirow.data[uicell.templateProperty]}}'
                                                ng-fileupload>上传</a> <a ng-show="uicell.value"
                                                href="javascript:;"
                                                ng-click="viewFile(uirow.data.cjmxdm,uicell.isRefXm)">预览({{uirow.data.fjsl}})</a>
                                            <a ng-show="uicell.value" href="javascript:;"
                                                ng-click="delFile(uirow.data.cjmxdm,uicell)">删除</a>
                                            <a ng-href="/download.sword?ctrl=DemoCtrl_downloadallfile&mbpath={{uicell.cjmbFileUrl}}{{getAuditParams()}}"
                                               target="_blank">模板</a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div ng-if="uicell.dataType=='upload'&&!uirow.id">
                                            <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="exeCommand({action:'saveRow',tabid:uitab.id},uirow)">保存</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div ng-if="uicell.dataType=='fileselect'">
                                            <a href="javascript:;" ng-click="fileSelect(uirow.id)">获取</a>
                                            <a ng-show="uicell.value" href="javascript:;"
                                                ng-click="viewFile(uirow.id)">预览</a>
                                        </div> <input ng-if="uicell.dataType=='number'"
                                        onchange="window.changeflag=true"
                                        ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}"
                                        ng-init="numberCellChange(uitab,$index);numberInit(uicell);"
                                        ng-focus="inputFocus(uicell)"
                                        ng-paste-text ng-paste-cell='uicell' ng-paste-row='uirow' ng-paste-table="uitab.table.tbody" ng-paste-tab="uitab"
                                        ng-blur="uicell.validate();exeFuncs(uitab,uicell,uirow.rowIndex,$index);sumRowRefresh(uitab);changeReport(uitab)"
                                        style="width: 100%; text-align: right;" type="text"
                                        ng-model="uicell.value" /> <!-- ng-class="{'font-bold-row',uitab.table.fontBoldRows&&uitab.table.fontBoldRows.indexOf($index)>=0}" -->
                                        <input ng-if="uicell.dataType=='datetime'"
                                        onchange="window.changeflag=true"
                                        ng-focus="inputFocus(uicell)"
                                        ng-blur="uicell.validate();exeFuncs(uitab)"
                                        ng-class="{'font-bold-row':uicell.font.bold}"
                                        ng-format="{{uicell.format}}" type="text" ng-datetimepicker
                                        ng-timepicker="{{uicell.timepicker}}"
                                        style="width: 100%;" ng-model="uicell.value"
                                        class="l_member_date"
                                        ng-paste-text ng-paste-cell="uicell" ng-paste-row="uirow" ng-paste-table="uitab.table.tbody" ng-paste-tab="uitab">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-if="uitab.table.sumRow"
                                    style="height: 28px; color: #858585;">
                                    <td style="padding: 10px 9px; font-size: 14px;"
                                        ng-repeat="col in uitab.table.columns" ng-hide="col.hide"
                                        ng-style="{'text-align':col.align}"><span
                                        ng-if="$index==0">合计</span> <span
                                        ng-if="$index!=0&&!col.sumCol">――</span> <span
                                        ng-if="$index!=0&&col.sumCol">{{col.sum}}</span></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: So you create 3000 watchers on your 3000 cells? Maybe you should try a different approach without watchers. Maybe bind the same onChange() on the inputs or cells.

Comment: I replaced the whole thing with Object.defineProperty, because I found out generating that table with 2 'ng-repeat' and nothing else will spend like 4 seconds on my testing environment, which is not acceptable and already reach its limit. After I replace it with pure javascript and using defineProperty (so it's still data driven), it costs like 800ms to generate the whole thing with some event listener bindings.